# Python: Appending a function that yields to a list?

Tags: python, list, yield

Hello and thanks for looking at my question! I was recently introduced to generators and I read the about on 'The Python yield keyword explained'. From my understanding, yield is generated on the fly, cannot be indexed and will remember where it left off after the yield command has been executed (correct me if I'm wrong I'm still new to this).

My question is then why does:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [['4A'],['5A','5B','5C'],['7A','7B']]

y = list()

for combination in x:
    for i in range(1,len(combination)+1):
        y.append(list(combinations(combination,i)))
print y # [[('4A',)], [('5A',), ('5B',), ('5C',)], 
        # [('5A', '5B'), ('5A', '5C'), ('5B', '5C')], 
        # [('5A', '5B', '5C')], [('7A',), ('7B',)], [('7A', '7B')]]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [['4A'],['5A','5B','5C'],['7A','7B']]

y = list()

for combination in x:
    for i in range(1,len(combination)+1):
        y.append((combinations(combination,i)))
print y
```

Since I am appending the combinations to y straight after it is yielded why is it that when it is appended in a list form it works, but when I do it normally, it doesn't?

Comment: A generator is itself an object. In the first case you're append the result of passing one to the `list` constructor to the `y` list. However in the second case you append the generator object itself to that list rather than a `list` created from one.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `list(generator_function())`, `generator_function` is iterated to exhaustion, and each element is stored in a list. So, these three operations are doing the same thing:

```
l = list(generator_function())
...
l = [x for x in generator_function()]
...
l = []
for x in generator_function():
    l.append(x)
```

In your example, without including `list(..)`, you're just appending the `combinations` generator object to the `y`. With `list(...)`, you're iterating over the `combinations` generator to build a `list` object, and then appending that to `y`.